# SonarQube 5.4: How to define dashboard (or filter) for a particular subset of my projects?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

Our enterprise is very large (~100 projects), and divided up into teams (~10 to 20 projects per team).  Assume that the teams have names like "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", etc.

I'd like to create a dashboard with a "Measure Filter as List" widget which only displays the projects of a particular team.  I created a manual metric "team_name", but I apparently cannot filter on string-valued metrics on SonarQube 5.4.  :-(

One suggestion I've seen would be create manual metric "team_num" and assign numbers to each (e.g., Alpha=1, Bravo=2, Charlie=3, etc.), but this seems inelegant.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The only best solution I see is to use the commercial product Governance : http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/governance/